# Extended BNF syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, bnf, ebnf

I try to find the Extended BNF (EBNF) nice syntax highlighting. Can't find it through the Google. Anybody know the link?

Thank you.

Comment: What editor are you using? What's the problem you faced?

A little googling reveals:
[vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=545)
[ebnf-textmate-bundle](https://github.com/arne-schroppe/ebnf-textmate-bundle/) (which can be used in Sublime Text)

Comment: I tried Notedpad++, you can create user defined language with your custom highlighting. Once I finish it I might put it somewhere for download.

Comment: There is also dead simple BNF Mode for Emacs: https://github.com/sergeyklay/bnf-mode

Answer (score 1):

It is still work in progress but it does job partly.

[image: EBNF-Notepad++ highlighter]

Check this github page i created: [EBNF](https://github.com/bluePlayer/practices/tree/master/EBNF)